# My Wifi is not woking

Tags: wifi

I installed Elementary OS and the wifi was working initially. Then i started using my bluetooth earphones and the internet started cutting off. After restart, the wifi has completely disappeared with just the Wired Connection available. Any ideas on how to get Wifi back?

Result of rfkill list all:

0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

Result of: sudo lshw -c network
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
logical name: enp2s0
version: 10
serial: 68:f7:28:10:b0:a5
size: 100Mbit/s
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.1.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
resources: irq:32 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90a04000-90a04fff memory:90a00000-90a03fff

Answer (score 0):

When you run `~$ sudo dmesg`, you will get a log of all processes. If there are any problems with particular processes, they should show up in RED. Less critical processes that may be problematic are shown in bold-type.

It may be that the network card has stopped working.  If so, it may be highlighted in RED. Note what it says, as it also provides information on how to resolve the problem. Your exact network card (ethernet interface) model should be in the detail provided.

The log may suggest you go to https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/ to search for, and download, the exact driver you require. Finding it is relatively easy; finding the download page is a little more difficult, but possible.

An alternative would be to execute `~$ sudo apt install linux-firmware-nonfree`. No harm should come to your system. Reboot and check that the you can connect to WI-FI.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I found the solution myself.

Apparently the problem is due to the Realtek 8822c video card driver (which is missing the rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin file needed to correctly load the rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin driver)

The solution is to download the latest version of linux-firmware from:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/snapshot/linux-firmware-20200918.tar.gz

Extract and copy the contents of the rtw88 folder to /lib/firmware/rtw88

Restart the operating system.

When restarting the wifi card will be fully functional!

Comment: Hello, could you kindly check in Appcenter if there is a driver for Realtek 8822c?